# Remove duplicate values from a vector<vector<string>>, not case sensitive? c++

Tags: c++

Hi i'm trying to remove duplicate values from my vector.
It is set up as a vector. This vector contains a list of vectors, in each of the interior vectors is 3 strings.

I tried:

```
removeCopies.erase( unique(removeCopies.begin(), removeCopies.end() ), removeCopies.end());
```

but it still leaves some strings inside the interior vector like:

```
mainVector: {
interiorVector1: string 1: "book", string 2: "noun", string3: "A book"
interiorVector2: string 1: "book", string 2: "noun", string3: "a BOok"
}
```

I also can't just change it all to lowercase, I can't edit the values inside of the vector.

If you need a better explanation, please ask. Thank you.

edit:

I tried

```
unique(stringVec.begin(), stringVec.end(), [](const string &a, const string 
&b) { return lowercase(a) == lowercase(b); }), stringVec.end()
```

where lowercase() turns the entire string to lowercase. But it doesn't allow me to access the interior vector strings to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Just like [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) accepts a *BinaryPredicate* that in the case of `unique` is used for equals-comparison:

```
template< class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate >
constexpr ForwardIt unique( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p );
```

If you provide a case-insensitive predicate, then it should work just fine. I recommend [`boost::iequals`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/iequals.html) if you don't want to re-invent the wheel.

The following code won't work for your specific nested-vector example, but if you only had strings inside the vector the resultant code would look something like:

```
removeCopies.erase(std::unique(begin(removeCopies), end(removeCopies), boost::iequals), end(removeCopies));
```

In your case, you'll probably want to write a custom [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that internally uses `iequals` to perform element-wise comparison.

Edit: Here is a discount-version of `iequals`:

```
bool iequals(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
   if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
      return false;
   for(size_t i = 0; i < lhs.size(); ++i)
   {
       if (std::tolower(lhs[i]) != std::tolower(rhs[i]))
          return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: ah I believe we are not allowed to use external libraries like boost.

Comment: @code1331: It's fairly straightforward to write your own version of `iequals`. Use [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) (or `std::tolower`) to compare characters between strings.

Comment: I tried

string lowercase(string x)
{

  transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), [](char x) { return tolower(x); });
  return x;

}

unique(stringVec.begin(), stringVec.end(),
        [](const string &a, const string &b) { return lowercase(a) == lowercase(b); }

      ),

      stringVec.end()

sorry it wont let me format.

Comment: @code1331 you don't need to declare a temporary string and use `std::transform`. You will get better performance with a regular loop that indexes into both the strings for comparison (and as a result will terminate after the minimum length). Inside the loop use `std::tolower` to get a lowercase version of each character in the respective strings. Then compare those characters for equivalance.